# Bibliography: Edition number raised to the left of the year

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

For my paper at university, in the bibliography, I need to raise the edition’s number to the left of the year, like here (where Auflage = edition):
[image]

Until now, I’ve got the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-authoryear, innamebeforetitle=true, innameidem=true, maxcitenames=2, dashed=false]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{ineditor}{sortname}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{multinamedelim}{\addspace\slash\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias*[bib]{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\adddot\space}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\slash}
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\slash}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \bibstring{in}%
  \printunit{\intitlepunct}}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\addnbthinspace}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\urlstyle{same}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{URL: <\url{#1}>}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  editor  = {Hrsg\adddot},
  editors = {Hrsg\adddot},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{\textsuperscript{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}
@incollection{Baldinger,
author = {Baldinger, Kurt},
title = {Semasiologie und Onomasiologie},
booktitle = {2. Teilband},
publisher = {De Gruyter Mouton},
year = {2008},
editor = {Posner, Roland and Robering, Klaus and Sebeok, Thomas},
edition = 3
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{literatur}

\begin{document}

\cite{Baldinger}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I’ve already consulted some posts from a [German stackexchange](https://golatex.de/viewtopic.php?t=16237) but somehow, by following their examples, I only reach to a raised edition number at the wrong position. But I need it raised right before the year.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bibmacro `date+extrayear` was renamed to `date+extradate` (in v3.8 [2017-11-04]). In principle the code from https://golatex.de/viewtopic.php?p=77661#p77661 can be reused with just a few modifications if you keep in mind that the definition in `ext-authoryear` differs slightly from the original (cf. [`ext-authoryear-common.bbx`, ll. 39-45 in v0.13](https://github.com/moewew/biblatex-ext/blob/9d79bafff65174186d3f99ad7282381f0b40bb3e/ext-authoryear-common.bbx#L39-L45)).

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  innamebeforetitle=true,
  innameidem=true,
  maxcitenames=2,
  dashed=false
]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{ineditor}{sortname}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\slash}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{multinamedelim}{\addspace\slash\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\adddot\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat{superedition}{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[\blx@delimcontext labeldate]{%
       \printfield[superedition]{edition}%
       \global\clearfield{edition}%
       \iflabeldateisdate
         {\printdateextra}
         {\printlabeldateextra}}}}
\makeatother

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \bibstring{in}%
  \printunit{\intitlepunct}}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\addnbthinspace}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\urlstyle{same}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{URL: <\url{#1}>}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  editor  = {Hrsg\adddot},
  editors = {Hrsg\adddot},
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Baldinger,
  author    = {Baldinger, Kurt},
  title     = {Semasiologie und Onomasiologie},
  maintitle = {Semiotik / Semiotics},
  booktitle = {2.~Teilband},
  publisher = {De Gruyter Mouton},
  year      = {2008},
  editor    = {Posner, Roland and Robering, Klaus and Sebeok, Thomas},
  edition   = 3
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{Baldinger,sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Baldinger, Kurt (32008). „Semasiologie und Onomasiologie“, in: Posner, Roland / Robering, Klaus / Sebeok, Thomas (Hrsg.). Semiotik / Semiotics. 2. Teilband. De Gruyter Mouton.]