# Biblatex: edition in superscript behind title

Tags: biblatex

I am writing a dissertation at the Leibniz Universität Hannover Germany. I need "ibid" ("ebd." in German) so I took `authoryear-icomp` for `biblatex`. Citestyle looks like: "(vgl. Bauer/Hurrelmann 2021, S. 21)" and "(ebd. S. 23)". My problem is the bibliography it has to look like:

[image]

The problem is the edition in superscript behind the title.

My sample Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,ngerman,oneside,usegeometry,parskip=false]{scrartcl}  %listof=entryprefix,listof=leveldown,listof=totoc, bibgerm,
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math} %lädt fontspec,

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Bibliographie
\usepackage[backend=biber, giveninits=true, maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=5, url=false, isbn=false, doi=false, dashed=false, style=authoryear-icomp, hyperref=true, sortcites=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addslash}% Slash Autoren Meyer/Müller
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}% Slash Meyer/Müller
\DeclareDelimFormat[parencite]{multinamedelim}{\slash}% Hannover Müller/Meier
\DeclareDelimAlias*[parencite]{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}% Hannover Müller/Meier

\AtEveryBibitem{% without publisher
    \clearlist{publisher}
    \clearfield{pagetotal}
}

\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space} %Doppelpunkt nach (2023):; 

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{ %anstatt und andere : et all 
    andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},
}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib} 
@book{blankertz1991,
    title = {Theorien und {{Modelle}} der {{Didaktik}}},
    author = {Blankertz, Herwig},
    date = {1991},
    edition = {13},
    publisher = {{Juventa-Verlag}},

}
@book{bauer2021,
    title = {Einführung in die Sozialisationstheorie: das Modell der produktiven Realitätsverarbeitung (MpR)},
    shorttitle = {Einführung in die Sozialisationstheorie},
    author = {Bauer, Ullrich and Hurrelmann, Klaus},
    date = {2021},
    edition = {14},
    publisher = {{Beltz}},
    location = {{Weinheim Basel}},
    abstract = {Einführung in die psychologischen und soziologischen Theorien der Sozialisation. (ekz)},
    isbn = {978-3-407-25885-4},
    langid = {german},
    pagetotal = {350},
    file = {/home/dirk/Zotero/storage/FG5DYMBX/bauer2021.pdf}
}

\end{filecontents*}
\textcite{blankertz1991}, \textcite{bauer2021}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For entries that have an `edition` field the title is printed by the bibmacro `maintitle+title` or `maintitle+booktitle`. We redefine those macros to include code to typeset a superscript edition similar to [Bibliography: Edition number raised to the left of the year](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/611447/35864) or [biblatex-verbose: edition as superscript in front of year](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141985/35864).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,ngerman,oneside,usegeometry,parskip=false]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=authoryear-icomp, 
  maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=5,
  giveninits=true, uniquename=init,
  url=false, isbn=false, doi=false,
  dashed=false,
]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
  andothers = {et\,al\adddot},
}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addslash}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}


\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearlist{publisher}%
  \clearfield{pagetotal}%
}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat{supered}{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\newbibmacro{superedition}{%
  \setunit{}%
  \printfield[supered]{edition}%
  \clearfield{edition}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{maintitle+title}{%
  \iffieldsequal{maintitle}{title}
    {\clearfield{maintitle}%
     \clearfield{mainsubtitle}%
     \clearfield{maintitleaddon}}
    {\iffieldundef{maintitle}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{maintitle}%
        \newunit\newblock
        \iffieldundef{volume}
          {}
          {\printfield{volume}%
           \printfield{part}%
           \setunit{\addcolon\space}}}}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \usebibmacro{superedition}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{maintitle+booktitle}{%
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{maintitle}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \iffieldundef{volume}
       {}
       {\printfield{volume}%
        \printfield{part}%
        \setunit{\addcolon\space}}}%
  \usebibmacro{booktitle}%
  \usebibmacro{superedition}%
  \newunit}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib} 
@book{blankertz1991,
  author    = {Blankertz, Herwig},
  title     = {Theorien und Modelle der Didaktik},
  date      = {1991},
  edition   = {13},
  publisher = {Juventa-Verlag},
  location  = {Weinheim},
}
@book{bauer2021,
  author    = {Bauer, Ullrich and Hurrelmann, Klaus},
  title     = {Einführung in die Sozialisationstheorie},
  subtitle  = {Das Modell der produktiven Realitätsverarbeitung (MpR)},
  date      = {2021},
  edition   = {14},
  publisher = {Beltz},
  location  = {Weinheim Basel},
  isbn      = {978-3-407-25885-4},
  langid    = {german},
  pagetotal = {350},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\textcite{blankertz1991}

\textcite{bauer2021}

\parencite{blankertz1991}

\parencite{bauer2021}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: Blankertz, H. (1991): Theorien und Modelle der Didaktik13. Weinheim.]

Comment: It works perfectly thanks for your efforts.

Comment: @Dobutrex Glad it works. If the answer solved your issue, please consider accepting it (https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). That way the question is marked as resolved.